# How to add Dynamic elements in the reverse direction to a Uiscrollview in IOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiscrollview

I had a scrollview in my application with dynamic elements which i am adding from right to left like this

```
if(array.count>0)
    {
          [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:777] removeFromSuperview];

    float x=315.0;
    float width=0.0;
    UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 52,245,20)];
    scroll.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    scroll.tag=777;
    [scroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(70,245)];
    scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;

    for(int i =0; i <[array count] ; i++)
    {

        UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:133.0/255.0 green:155.0/255.0 blue:179.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 2;


        [btn setTitle:[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@“ggg”] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
        [btn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:10.0]];
       CGSize size = [btn.titleLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:
        @{NSFontAttributeName:
              [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:10.0]}];
        x=x-(size.width+10);

        //or whatever font you're using
        [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(x,0,size.width+10,15)];
        [scroll addSubview:btn];
         width=width+x;
         x=x-5;
    }

       scroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake((width+50),20);
        // [scroll setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:scroll];
```

}

here everything working very fine,but i am not able to scroll to the last element added at the left.scroll was only allowing me to scroll up to 70 from left to right .Can anybody tell me where i am going wrong on this?

Comment: try this scroll.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

Comment: @johnykumar sorry no luck

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)addButtonInScrollViewFromArray:(NSArray *)array{
NSInteger arrayCount=array.count;
NSInteger numberIteration=0;
CGFloat buttonXValue=300;
UIScrollView *buttonScrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 360, 60)];
while (numberIteration<arrayCount) {
    UIButton *buttonCreated=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    buttonCreated.frame=CGRectMake(buttonXValue,5, 50, 50);
    buttonXValue-=60;
    [buttonCreated setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button%d",numberIteration] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonScrollView addSubview:buttonCreated];
    numberIteration++;
}
CGFloat totalLength=numberIteration*60;
buttonScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(totalLength,60);
```

}

> this function you can pass the array

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to below one

```
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x+size.width+10,20);
```